# Spring Cloud Canary Deployment

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-zuul, canary-deployment

I have a spring cloud micro service with Zuul running on docker.

Requirement:

I want to create canary deployment with specific requirement as we will have x clients and I want to canary test with y specific clients (using email or username).

Can I configure the gateway to route requests to the new version of the micro-service for these y clients?

Comment: sure you can do that , I think is that routing  in zuul you have to configure path and service_id for client and do what you want it will route all request to in or you can do that with zuulfilter  which is check request headers where came from and route where you want

Answer (score 0):

So you can do that via configuration or dynamic routing but i think first idom is not good for generic part every client you have to define it again and again but second one is more good

```
@Component
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final String REQUEST_PATH = "/special-customer-product-request-url";
    private static final String TARGET_SERVICE = "special-customer-service";
    private static final String HTTP_METHOD = "POST or GET";

    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public PostOrdersFilter(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
        String method = request.getMethod();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        return HTTP_METHOD.equalsIgnoreCase(method) && requestURI.startsWith(REQUEST_PATH);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        List<ServiceInstance> instances = discoveryClient.getInstances(TARGET_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (instances != null && instances.size() > 0) {
                context.setRouteHost(instances.get(0).getUri().toURL());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Target service instance not found!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't get service URL!", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```